# How to pass in a class property into a function in python and use it as a property of the class

Tags: python

not sure if this question has been asked before, maybe the way that I've been wording the question is wrong but here goes,

Suppose I have the code below:

```
class House:

    def __init__(self):
        self.living_room = "living_room"
        self.bed_room = "bed_room"
        self.garage = "garage"

def test(house,room):
   print(house.room) #I know I can't write it this way, but just as an example of what I'm hoping to achieve
```

I want to pass in the property of the `House` class to the function `test` for the arguement `room` such that if `room` is `garage` then the `test` function prints out `"garage"` and if `room` is `bed_room` then `"bed_room"` gets printed out. Is there a way of achieving this? I prefer not to have multiple functions doing the same thing apart from accessing different properties of the class. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a class attribute you can use `__getattribute__` method. Also, you should have already created class instance:

```
class House:
    def __init__(self):
        self.living_room = "living_room"
        self.bed_room = "bed_room_property"
        self.garage = "garage"

my_house = House()

def test(house,room):
   print(house.__getattribute__(room))

test(my_house, 'bed_room')
```

Output:

```
bed_room_property
```

Comment: `__getattribute__` is only part of attribute resolution. The `getattr` function is the tool to use here.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That's true, but anyway `getattr()` calls `__getattribute__`

Comment: `__getattribute__` is *one* of the things `getattr` calls. It also tries `__getattr__`. `__getattribute__` is not responsible for performing the `__getattr__` fallback, and directly calling `__getattribute__` will fail to find attributes implemented through `__getattr__`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class House:

    def __init__(self):
        self.living_room = "living_room"
        self.bed_room = "bed_room"
        self.garage = "garage"

# In order to use the class properties an object must be created

a=House()#Here a is the object of the class House

def test(room):
    print(room)


#The function test is called with the parameter

test(a.living_room)#In a.living_room a is the object,living_room is attribute of House

#Likewise you can call the other attributes of the class and print it with the 
function test
```